# .click() Child Radio Triggers: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

I have looked at other questions regarding this console error. None of which seem to hold the answer to my dilemma. I mainly see issues with APIs co-existing, and other more complex situations that mine...

The script I'm trying to write simply clicks a child input (radio) when the parent is clicked. this is easily the tiniest function I have written in a long time, yet I'm vexed. Why is such a small script not working? I've even made a new (simple) html file with just the html for these two buttons, and just the jquery to make them do what I want. I tried changing the names of the inputs to differing names. No dice. It seems as though jQuery is being thrown into an infinite loop.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I have seen a couple reported bugs on jQuery's site, but they were people using pseudo-selectors improperly (and other bogus "bugs"). I can't figure this out! Thanks in advance for any guidance here...

***UPDATE: Solution***
Use the `<label>` as the button. Most browsers utilize the label as a "click the accompanying input". So NO JQUERY REQUIRED in this case. Thanks everybody who contributed below!!! I wanted to mark a few as the answer. But couldn't...

**jQuery Version Used**

jQuery 1.9.0

**HTML**

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="toggle">
        <div class="button">
            <input name="ship-to" type="radio" checked="checked" value="billing">
            <label for="ship-to">Ship to my billing address</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
        <div class="button">
            <input name="ship-to" type="radio" value="different">
            <label for="ship-to">Ship to different address</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Buttons */
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this).children('input');
        $radio.click();
    });
});
```

**Console Error**

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
a
a.matches
st.extend.filter
st.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
st.event.dispatch
y.handle
st.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
st.extend.each
st.fn.st.each
st.fn.extend.trigger
st.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
st.event.dispatch
y.handle
st.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
st.extend.each
st.fn.st.each
```

... This goes on for quite sometime.

Comment: The click on the button triggers the click on the radio, which bubbles up to the button, which triggers the click on the radio, which bubbles up to the button, which triggers the click on the radio, which bubbles up to the button, which triggers the click on the radio, which bubbles up to the button, until you receive said error.

Comment: Why you want to fire child radio button click, while clicking on parent?

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Why do I want to? The parent div acts like a button. The radio input is there for form behavior. And it is more user friendly to have a larger button to click (rather than a tiny radio input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `label` needs to target the ID of an `input` element, not the name.

Remove all the JavaScript. Then change your HTML as follows:

```
<input name="ship-to" id="ship-to-billing" type="radio" checked="checked" value="billing">
<label for="ship-to-billing">Ship to my billing address</label>
```

and:

```
<input name="ship-to" id="ship-to-different" type="radio" value="different">
<label for="ship-to-different">Ship to different address</label>
```

Clicking on a label in most browsers will automatically trigger a click on the input element(s) with the *ID* named in the `for` attribute. This is a usability feature, and is the preferred solution to your problem.

Comment: That's a trip. I was taught to target the name attribute (label for=""). I suppose I could style the label as the "button"? That may eliminate the need for the jquery all together...

Comment: Correct -- you can style the label any way you want. It's `display:inline` by default, so `display:block` may be necessary depending on exactly how you want it to look.

Answer (score 4):

Do not fire Click event of radio Instead just set the radio button `checked` property. When you fire  a click event on the radio manually it bubbles up to the parent div click which in-turn causes a recursive loop.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bqB6n/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Buttons */
    $('.button').click(function(e){

        var $radio = $(this).children('input');
        $radio.prop('checked', !$radio.prop('checked')); 
       //Not sure if you need to toggle. if not use the below one.
        $radio.prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: I did try this (before you posted your answer) and the result was two radio buttons with the 'checked' property, and no toggle (back and forth). I will try this excerpt of code though. Maybe I'll have better luck :)

Comment: Yeah this works great. I appreciate the help. Kinda confused whether I should mark this is the answer (because technically I asked what the error was about) BUT this is (one of the) answer to my general need. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Because of event bubbling, clicking on the inputs also triggers the click handler on the containing DIV, which calls the handler, resulting in infinite recursion. The following code will detect these recursive clicks and ignore them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Buttons */
    var inside_button_click = false;
    $('.button').click(function(){
        if (!inside_button_click) {
            var $radio = $(this).children('input');
            inside_button_click = true;
            $radio.click();
            inside_button_click = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the event did not originate from the radio.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Buttons */
    $('.button').click(function(e.target){
        var $radio = $(this).children('input');
        if (e.target !== $radio[0]) {
            $radio.click();
        }
    });
});
```